# how to show the complete background image in a jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

so I realized if I have more content it shows the complete background image. Is there a neat way to do this?

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background: url('./assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center; margin-top: 120px;">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-t-3">

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add style `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`.

Comment: @yariash so background-size:contain works except it scales down the original image quite a lot. Is there a way to change the scale manually as well?

Answer (score 3):

I would experiment with using the `contain` or `cover` value for the `background-size` property:

```css
.jumbotron.test {
  background: url(http://www.outdoor-photos.com/_photo/4488849.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; /*** Try interchanging with contain/cover when using media queries for different results at different viewports. ***/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid test">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-t-3">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I tried your code with cover, it ended up looking like this and with contain it scales down the image quite significantly http://imgur.com/rSIFEo7

Comment: @MonaJalal Did you include `background-repeat: no-repeat`? or add `no-repeat` to the `background` property?

Answer (score 0):

```
  background:  bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat; //shorthand

div{
      background: #333 url('../img-url.jpg') no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html as below:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background: url('variable-scope-ruby.jpg') no-repeat center center; margin-top: 120px;">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-y-3">       
    <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

also add below css style:

```
<style>
.lead{
  padding: 30px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

and update `.lead` padding as your requirement.